# Clone moment js object

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

I have momentjs object in state

```
  state = {
     startDate: getNow() //this funtion return a momemtJS object
    }
```

in one function, I need to get the date one year before startDate

```
const dateBeforeOneYear = this.state.startDate.subtract(1, 'years');
```

But if I do like this, I modify the state by mistake

So I try to copy the state

```
const copyStartDate = {...this.state.startDate}

const copyStartDate = this.state.startDate.subtract(1, 'years');
```

But now I get the error, substract is not a function, I guess because copyStartDate is no more MomemntJs

Comment: store date only in state variable, anytime you want moment object pass the date into moment, that will be a better approach i think.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[There's a method](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/moment-clone/) to clone a moment object:

```
const yearBefore = this.state.startDate.clone().subtract(1, 'years');
```

It would also be a better idea to store a serialisable representation of the date in your component state, such as the result of calling `.valueOf()` on either a Date or a Moment, either of which returns the number of milliseconds since the UNIX epoch.

Answer (score 15):

moment.js has its own api for cloning moment object.

```
var copy = momentObj.clone();
```

And I agree on storing dates serialize representation instead of Object in store.

Answer (score 2):

It's also possible to copy a `moment` object through it's constructor. Like so

```js
const firstMoment = moment("2020-08-18");
const clone = moment(firstMoment);
```